# React Maximum update depth exceeded in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-context

In my react functional component, I have a function that is executed to toggle the checkboxes as selected or unselected. It works fine.

The function (inside **Parent component**) goes like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {

const { state, dispatch } = useContext(FilterContext);

const onChange = useCallback((value) => {
(item) => {
  const { name, selected } = item;
 
  // this "name" comes from another sibling component on the mount, and then from child component (sideAccordian) on click

  const selectedFilters = state.identifiers_checkbox.selected_checkboxes.find(
    (obj) => obj === name
  );

  const selected_checkboxes = selectedFilters
    ? state.identifiers_checkbox.selected_checkboxes.filter(
        (obj) => obj !== name
      )
    : [...state.identifiers_checkbox.selected_checkboxes, name];

  const toggled_checkboxes = {
    selected_checkboxes,
    options_checkbox: [
      ...state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox.map((filter) => {
        return {
          ...filter,
          options: filter.options.map((option, i) => {
            return name === option.name
              ? {
                  ...option,
                  selected,
                }
              : option;
          }),
        };
      }),
    ],
  };

  dispatch({
    type: "update-checkboxes",
    payload: {
      checkboxSelected: true,
      selected_checkboxes: toggled_checkboxes.selected_checkboxes,
      options_checkbox: toggled_checkboxes.options_checkbox,
    },
  });
},
[
  dispatch,
  state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox,
  state.identifiers_checkbox.selected_checkboxes,
]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (info.prevui === "intervention") {
      if (state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox.length > 1) {
        onChange({ name: info.abbr, selected: 1 });
      }
    }
  }, [
    info.abbr,
    info.prevui,
    dispatch,
    state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox.length,
    // onChange,
  ]);


return (
       <div>
        {
            state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox.length > 1 ? (
             <SideAccordian
               filterstate={state.identifiers_checkbox}
               onChange={onChange}
             />
             ) : (
                <h6 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>No Options Available</h6>
             )
         }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Child Component**

```
export default function SideAccordian(props) {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
    const classes = useStyles();

    useEffect(() => {
        setOptions(props.filterprop);
    }, [props]);

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            {
                options.map((ele, id) => (
                    <Accordion key={id} defaultExpanded={true}>
                        <AccordionSummary
                            key={ele.key}
                            expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                            aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                            id="panel1a-header"
                        >
                        </AccordionSummary>
                        {ele.options.map((item, i) => {
                            return (
                                <AccordionDetails key={i}>
                                    <IndeterminateInput
                                        key={i}
                                        id={i}
                                        name={item.name}
                                        value={item.label}
                                        selected={item.selected}
                                        onChange={props.onChange}
                                    />
                                </AccordionDetails>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Accordion>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Additionally, I need to call `onChange()` function as the component mounts & then automatically mark any of the checkboxes as selected according to the name of the checkbox passed as an argument.

The handler function `onChange()` works fine on clicking the checkbox, but when trying to invoke it on mount on the basis of a particular condition, it doesn't work.

As soon as the component mounts:

If `onChange()` is included in the dependency array, it throws `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

If removed from the dependency array, it works but keeps throwing error `each Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'onChange'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`.

Since, I need to execute this function only once on render also i.e. (when info.prevui === intervention' & info.prevui does not change every time ), this error behavior of `useEffect()` is out of my understanding.

Can anyone please help out to understand and provide any working hint/solution for the same?

Thanks

Comment: the error indicates that state is set in an infinite loop. maybe you can try implementing componentDidUpdate function?

Comment: @AkinoArchilles Since I am using functional component, using componentDidUpdate() has the same effect as hook useEffect()

Comment: If `handleCheckboxChange` dispatches an action to update state that is a dependency in the effect which invokes `handleCheckboxChange` then that is likely the cause of your looping. You mention you want the effect to run when the component mounts, it does, but since you've added dependencies it will run any time a dependency updates. Does issue repro if you use an empty dependency array (`[]`)?

Comment: @DrewReese. Nope, if I pass empty dependency array [ ], the looping stops. But then as usual, the warning msgs occur: `React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'handleCheckboxChange' and 'info.abbr'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. And also, the checkbox which I need to get selected, e.g., `label1` (originally it is being passed from state 'info.abbr'), does not get `checked: true`

Comment: You *can* ignore warnings if you *truly* want an effect to run only once on mount. It sounds like the data you want though isn't immediately available when the component mounts, but rather comes a render cycle (or 2 or 3) later.

Comment: @DrewReese Ignoring the warnings is legitimate in case of react hooks? I mean, under what conditions, should this be followed?

Comment: Completely, they are *just* warnings, afterall, but like any warning, you should use caution when deciding to ignore it. The most typical use-case I consider is the `componentDidMount` condition where you know with certainty you only want a hook to run once total during the life of the component and all data is available at *that* time. The linter can't possibly know your use-case so it is a very general blanket check.

Comment: Your hint did work. I changed like this:  `useEffect(() => {
        if (info.prevui === 'intervention') {
            if (state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox.length > 1) {
                handleCheckboxChange(info.abbr);
            }
        }
    }, [info.abbr, state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox.length, info.prevui]);`.      The functionality I required did work, but now I am just left with a warning : `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleCheckboxChange'. Either includes it or remove the dependency array`, which I think I can ignore now :D

Comment: If your IDE doesn't suggest it, `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` a line above the dependency array will stifle the warning, but again, caution should be used because if you ever update the hook logic and dependencies *do* change this will silently swallow them. You may also try a more specific dependency, `state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox.length`?

Comment: You're right. I included state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox.length already in the useEffect()

Comment: @DrewReese The problem still exists somehow. Can you help a bit in-depth?

Comment: Is it possible for you to reproduce this issue into a *running* codesandbox? It doesn't need to be your entire codebase, but just enough to reproduce the render looping.

Comment: Sure. I will create one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222700/discussion-between-bubble-cord-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why there's an infinite render loop in your code when you include the `onChange` handler in the effect dependencies is because when whenever the `handleCheckboxChange` function is called, the `handleCheckboxChange` function is redefined due to `state.identifiers_checkbox.selected_checkboxes` and `state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox` in the dependency array since both of them are updated in the redux state every time `handleCheckboxChange` is called.

Then, when you pass `onChange` into the dependency array of the `useEffect`, it runs the effect every time the `onChange` changes which is every time `handleCheckboxChange` is run - hence the infinite render loop.

So, the easiest way of fixing this would be to put `onChange` into a ref in the child component so you don't need to include it in the dependency array, that way it remains up-to-date in the effect, and doesn't cause an infinite render loop of doom.

```
  const onChangeRef = useRef(onChange);
  useEffect(()=>{onChangeRef.current = onChange},[onChange])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (info.prevui === "intervention") {
      if (state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox.length > 1) {
        onChangeRef.current({ name: info.abbr, selected: 1 });
      }
    }
  }, [
    info.abbr,
    info.prevui,
    dispatch,
    state.identifiers_checkbox.options_checkbox.length,
  ]);
```

For an example of this: The codesandbox you posted in the chat (with the `handleCheckBoxChange` in the useEffect which causes the infinite loop as handleCheckboxChange is created everytime the component re-renders:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-g7vh1

```
  useEffect(() => {
    handleCheckboxChange("ornge");

    setTimeout(() => {
      handleCheckboxChange("tmto");
    }, 5000);
  }, [handleCheckboxChange]);
```

Then fixed:
https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-loop-fix-4y6zm?file=/src/index.js

```
  const changeRef = useRef(handleCheckboxChange);
  useEffect(() => {
    changeRef.current = handleCheckboxChange;
  }, [handleCheckboxChange]);
  useEffect(() => {
    changeRef.current("ornge");

    setTimeout(() => {
      changeRef.current("tmto");
    }, 5000);
  }, []);
```

---

Elaboration as requested:

React's [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook returns a value that is mutable and will always remain referentially stable. Essentially for each render, changeRef always points to the same object in memory as it did before, thus what it refers to is stable. This is different than most things, because for instance `[]===[]` returns false because the arrays refer to different objects in memory.

`useRef` is known by React to create these mutable referentially stable objects, so they don't make it a requirement to pass them into the dependency arrays of any of the hooks as they know it isn't necessary.

By stuffing the `onChange` function into a ref and then making sure to update that ref whenever `onChange` changes via shallow equality, now we have a way to refer to the latest version of `onChange` without having to worry about adding it to the dependencies of the effect.

The reason why React has these dependency arrays to re-run the various hooks is because of [Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) - each time the function component renders, all the various functions and objects are recreated (although `useMemo`, `useCallback`, and `useState` allow for certain things to not be recreated every time). When a function is created, then it has a way to refer to all the variables in the scope that the function can see.

That's why something like the following works. Even though `test` goes out of scope before `funct` is called, `funct` has a closure around it so it can always see it as long as `funct` is in scope somewhere.

```
let funct;
{
 const test = 5;
 funct = ()=>{console.log(test)}
}
funct(); // logs 5
```

These closures are what React Hooks rely on to work as they do. It's also the reason why the eslint plugin react hooks has the `exhaustive-deps` piece, because if you don't include something, then by the time the value is used, it'll become [stale](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function).

React's `useRef` hook allows us to bypass the closures because the refs are able to be mutated, so using `ref.current` gives us whatever value has been put in there regardless of when the closure was created.

Comment: I was just refering to the component that has the `onChange` mentioned in the post as a child component, since you didn't post any component names or full code, I just had to guess.

Comment: My bad. I've updated my parent and child components accordingly. If now they help you out my query about passing in the child component

Comment: If I am not wrong, both of these code sandbox links are still giving error for missing handler ?

Comment: The second link's warning message is: `The 'handleCheckboxChange' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 66) change on every render.` which is basically them trying to be helpful in saying that the `useEffect` that I'm using to update the `changeRef` is running every time (which is intentional in this case) as it's a demonstration of things.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. The issue is now resolved! Not getting the dependency error anymore. Can you please help elaborate bitmore on how using ref worked exactly for this?

Comment: @bubble-cord, I've added a bunch of explanation and a couple links for you